# Laravel 5.5 returning view in Exceptions/Handler and empty csrf token

Tags: php, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

I have a custom URL that is rendering a view in `Exceptions\Handler.php`, but because that is not being passed through the web middleware it is not creating me a csrf token (I think)

The code:

```
/**
 * Render an exception into an HTTP response.
 *
 * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
 * @param  \Exception  $exception
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\Response
 */
public function render($request, Exception $exception)
{
    if($exception instanceof NotFoundHttpException)
    {
        if(customURL()) {
        {
            $controller = new CustomURLController();
            return $controller->home();
        }

        return response()->view('errors.missing',array(), 404);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $exception);
}
```

Comment: Got `StartSession` middleware active?

Comment: @Thielicious I'm not sure what that is

Comment: I've temporarily fixed it by excluding the url in the csrf middleware